# aspnetspell SpellAsYouType causing unwanted line break

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

```
@using ASPNetSpell;
@{
    ASPNetSpell.Razor.SpellAsYouType MyAsYouType = new ASPNetSpell.Razor.SpellAsYouType();
    MyAsYouType.InstallationPath = ("/Content/ASPNetSpellInclude");
    MyAsYouType.FieldsToSpellCheck = "Search_Data";
}
<div id="searchbar">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", new { @class = "search-box" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.TextBox("Search_Data", ViewBag.FilterValue as string, new { @class = "search-box" })
        <input type="image" src="~/Images/Search.gif" alt="Find Everything Catholic" style="display:inline" />
        @*@Html.Raw(MyAsYouType.getHtml())*@
    }
</div>
```

The  above code displays the image next to the textbox. If I uncomment the MyAsYouType line the image drops down a line.

The line is adding an element.style of display: block. If i remove this in chrome element inspector, it displays correctly.

I can not find the location to override this setting.

Thanks,
Doug

Comment: Why not simply add your own CSS to override that, rather than hope against hope that this plugin actually has that option available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your .cshtml:

```
<div id="searchbar">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", new { @class = "search-box" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.TextBox("Search_Data", ViewBag.FilterValue as string, new { @class = "search-box" })
        <input type="image" src="~/Images/Search.gif" alt="Find Everything Catholic" style="display:inline" />
        @*@Html.Raw(MyAsYouType.getHtml())*@
    }
</div>
```

Here's your added CSS:

```
.spellAsYouType { display: inline-block!important; }
```

That should solve your problem.

Comment: I found it at .livespell_textarea .ls_input